# MySQL JDBC driver connection string?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, cobol

How do I connect to a MySQL Database with the JDBC Driver?
This for Cobol, using Percobol software.

```
    DO-CONNECT.
     STRING "jdbc:mysql://gpiw.be/db;"
      DELIMITED BY SIZE
      "user=user_db;"
      DELIMITED BY SIZE
      "password=*********"
      DELIMITED BY SIZE
      INTO JdbcString
     EXEC SQL
      CONNECT
       TO :JdbcString
       DRIVER "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     END-EXEC
    .
```

What's wrong?

Sources:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/sqlstate_status_return_codes.html#28000

Comment: Hi there. Could you edit your question and add the message you are receiving?

Comment: I don't know anything about COBOL but I've used Scott Klement's JDBC stuff with RPG for a while, perhaps it will help you or at least give you some ideas of where to look for more help... Also it would be helpful if you told us what kind of error(s) you are getting. http://www.scottklement.com/jdbc/

Comment: Are you sure COBOL can use a **Java** based driver to connect? Would be *very* surprising (unless your COBOL program is running on a Java Virtual Machine)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know for certain that RPGLE can use JDBC and I've been told by guys here on SO (WarrenT and Buck Calabro I think) that COBOL can use the same JDBC library I use (Scott Klement's, linked above). Pretty cool.

Comment: PerCobol is an implementation of Cobol on a Java Machine

Comment: How did you arrive at the semi-colon as a separator from the links you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
    DO-CONNECT.
     STRING "jdbc:mysql://***ip****/***database**?"
      DELIMITED BY SIZE
      "user=****username****&"
      DELIMITED BY SIZE
      "password=****password******"
      DELIMITED BY SIZE
      INTO JdbcString
     EXEC SQL
      CONNECT
       TO :JdbcString
       DRIVER "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     END-EXEC
    .
```

Comment: You could probably do it in one string (as a normal JDBC URL with connection properties) without those `DELIMITED BY SIZE` sections